# Entity Framework 6.x adding massive list of pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, tfs, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

My question is basically what "should" I be checking in and what should I be excluding? Recently when adding a package that includes a dependency to Entity Framework Version 6.X (such as System.Data.SQLite), I get a huge amount of pending changes (over 4k).

Normally, I just check-in with default settings and don't ignore anything, assuming the files in MyProject\packages are handled automatically and the correct ones are getting checked in. The number of files is rather obscene and I feel like something must be wrong. This happens with every project as soon as I install: System.Data.SQLite but other packages which add Entity Framework as a dependency also do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never put the contents of a packages folder in source control. Your `.gitignore` / `.tfignore` should contain an entry for it. NuGet packages will be automatically restored based on the `packages.config` file when building.

Comment: Of course assuming that automatic restore of NuGet packages is enabled.

Comment: Done - following this guide to generate automatically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server

Has something about this changed recently in VS2017? Or, am I just now noticing because of the massive number of files associated with EF packages / dependencies?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks!

Ya, I'm used to having to do a restore and normally do it manually as it seems sometimes the automatic has issues with dependencies for projects with a lot of nuget packages.